# cannot find name "interface" inside static method typescript

Tags: typescript

Maybe this is a stupid question but can not find anything, help me.

I'm trying TS, and I happened to test an interface

```
interface HelloWorldTS {
        name : string;
    }
```

within this code.

```
class Startup {


    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World');

        return 0;
    }
}

Startup.main();
```

---

```
interface HelloWorldTS {
        name : string;
    }

class Startup {


    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World');

        TSInterface : HelloWorldTS = { name: "hello"};

        return 0;
    }


}

Startup.main();
```

but I make a error: cannot find name "HelloWorldTS", in this line `TSInterface : HelloWorldTS = { name: "hello"};`

My question is, if possible use an interface from a static method, and if so, what is my mistake. sorry for my bad English I hope you understand what I want to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing the keyword to declare a new variable like **let**

```
interface HelloWorldTS {
        name : string;
    }

class Startup {


    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World');

        let TSInterface : HelloWorldTS = { name: "hello"};

        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: oh man, I vote your answer, but still can not accept it, but accept it, thank you very much for your time.